# Warning react : setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Warning: setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This usually means you called setState() on an unmounted component. This is a no-op.

This is a react application, where a banner is fixed on the screen and passing random images. The way it was written is generating the warning in question.

```
import React from "react";
import Lightbox from "react-image-lightbox";
import logo from "./logo.png";

class Banner extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      images: [],
      currentImage: logo,
      isOpen: false,
      sidebarOpen: true
    };
  }

  async componentWillMount() {
    await this.getBanners();
    this.setState({ currentImage: this.state.images[0].url });

    setInterval(async () => {
      await this.getBanners();
    }, 300000);

    let i = 0;
    setInterval(
      () => {
        this.setState({ currentImage: this.state.images[i].url });
        if (i >= this.state.images.length - 1) {
          i = 0;
        } else {
          i++;
        }
      },
      10000,
      i
    );
  }

  async getBanners() {
    const data = await (await fetch("/api/banners/active")).json();
    if (data.true) {
      this.setState({ images: data.true });
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { isOpen } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        {isOpen && (
          <Lightbox
            mainSrc={this.state.currentImage}
            onCloseRequest={() => this.setState({ isOpen: false })}
          />
        )}
        <footer>
          <a>
            <img
              width={270}
              height="200"
              src={this.state.currentImage}
              onClick={() => this.setState({ isOpen: true })}
              alt="idk"
            />
          </a>
        </footer>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Banner;
```

Could anyone help improve this code?

Comment: Your setIntervals are going to happen forever, so if this gets mounted / unmounted your going to get lots of errors, and memory leaks.

Comment: Did any of the answers work for you? Consider [accepting one of them](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work#answer-5235) if that’s the case.

Answer (score 1):

You can put the numbers returned from `setInterval` on your instance and stop the intervals with `clearInterval` in `componentWillUnmount` so that they won't continue to run after the component has been unmounted.

```
class Banner extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.bannerInterval = null;
    this.currentImageInterval = null;
    this.state = {
      images: [],
      currentImage: logo,
      isOpen: false,
      sidebarOpen: true
    };
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    await this.getBanners();
    this.setState({ currentImage: this.state.images[0].url });

    this.bannerInterval = setInterval(async () => {
      await this.getBanners();
    }, 300000);

    let i = 0;
    this.currentImageInterval = setInterval(
      () => {
        this.setState({ currentImage: this.state.images[i].url });
        if (i >= this.state.images.length - 1) {
          i = 0;
        } else {
          i++;
        }
      },
      10000,
      i
    );
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.bannerInterval);
    clearInterval(this.currentImageInterval);
  }

  // ...
}
```

Comment: The problem is that the component is never unmounted. It is a fixed banner on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Use this template for any class-based component that has a state:

forgot about setState(), and use setComponentState declared down:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      // other fields...
      isUnmounted: false,
    };
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.setState({ isUnmounted: true });
  }

  setComponentState = (values) => {
    if (!this.state.isUnmounted) this.setState(values);
  };
}
```